# Prove for an ordinal $\alpha\ne 0$, exists an ordinal $\epsilon$ such that $\omega^\epsilon\le \alpha\le \omega^{\epsilon+1}$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Prove for an ordinal $\alpha\ne 0$, exists an ordinal $\epsilon$ such that $\omega^{\epsilon}\le \alpha\le \omega^{\epsilon+1}$

A hint is: Let $\theta$ be the smallest ordinal such that $\alpha<\omega^\theta$, prove that $\theta$ cannot be a limit ordinal.

I think once I prove that the least ordinal $\theta$ such that $\alpha<\omega^\theta$ is not a limit ordinal, then $\theta=\gamma^+$ some ordinal $\gamma$ as $\gamma\in\gamma^+$, by definition of "$<$" we have $\gamma<\theta$. Recall the fact that $\theta$ is the least ordinal such that $\alpha<\omega^{\theta}$, so $\alpha\ge \omega^\beta$ for any $\beta\le \theta$, in particular, $\alpha\ge \omega^{\gamma}$. So $\omega^\gamma\le \alpha\le \omega^{\gamma^+}$ as desired.

Suppose, in order to get a contradition, that $\theta$ is a non-zero limit ordinal($\theta$ cannot be zero since $\omega^0=1$ and $\alpha\ne 0$ so $\theta=0$  contradicts $\alpha<\omega^\theta$). I have stucked on proving that $\theta$ cannot be such an ordinal for a while... So could someone please help(on proving the hint)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $\theta$ is limit, $\omega^\theta$ is the supremum of the ordinals $\omega^\gamma$ with $\gamma<\theta$. Use this.

Comment: A slightly expanded version of the hint: Keep in mind that for ordinals, $\alpha\lt\beta$ is equivalent to $\alpha\in\beta$. What does this imply, given the definition of $\omega^\theta$?

Comment: Don't you mean $\omega^\epsilon\le\alpha\lt\omega^{\epsilon+1}$?

Comment: @bof I think here we have it, but the original question is just asking about $\omega^{\epsilon}\le\alpha\le\omega^{\epsilon+1}$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I did notice it and I think maybe after some manipulations I can get some result that contradicts the fact that $\theta$ is the least ordinal such that $\alpha<\omega^{\theta}$. Am I on the right track? But could you please explain a bit more on how can I see where the contradiction is?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Sorry I still cannot fully understand it. Could you please explain it? I have stuck on it for hours...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly expanded version of the hint(s) from the comments: keep in mind that if $\sigma$ is a limit ordinal, then we have $\sigma = \bigcup_{\tau\lt\sigma}\tau$; also, if $\sigma$ is a limit ordinal, then $\omega^\sigma$ is a limit ordinal with $\omega^\sigma = \bigcup_{\tau\lt\sigma}\omega^\tau$.  Now, saying that $\alpha\lt\omega^\sigma$ is the same as saying that $\alpha\in\omega^\sigma$, and thus that $\alpha\in\bigcup_{\tau\lt\sigma}\omega^\tau$.

Now, what is the definition of $\alpha\in\bigcup_i S_i$? That is, under what conditions do we say that membership in a union holds?

Comment: Saying $\alpha\in \bigcup_{\tau<\sigma}\omega^\tau$ is to say that $\alpha\in \omega^{\tau}$ for some $\tau<\sigma$. Thus $\alpha< \omega^{\tau}$ for some $\tau<\sigma$ and here is the contradiction. Is that correct?

Comment: @user464003 That's exactly it!